# Dispatch an action with the most recent React state value as argument

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am currently migrating to ReactJS Hooks and I am feeling stuck among the most basic of things - I need to dispatch an action which takes the most updated state value as an argument.

The state is defined like this:

```
const [roomId, setRoomId] = useState("");
```

I have a helper function that is called when clicking a button. The helper function dispatches an action that uses `roomId` as argument as follows:

```
const _handleCreateRoom = () => {
    let generatedRoomId = generateCode();
    setRoomId(generatedRoomId);
    dispatch(createRoom(roomId));
}
```

However what is happening is that the `roomId` state is being updated only *after* the action is being dispatched, making the action being called with a null argument.

I understand the reason is asynchronistic behaviour due to closures however I cannot come up with a recommended design to solve this seemingly trivial problem / situation.

Comment: why not just `dispatch(createRoom(generatedRoomId))` ?

Comment: @D.B.K. Fair comment and that is what I ended up using...but I feel it is a temporary solution until I learn a better (and recommended) design of using states within actions

Comment: yessir. useEffect would be the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right about the async nature of `setRoomId` causing this problem.

There's no guarantee that calling `setRoomId` will immediately set the roomId (as its not synchronous), so you cant really expect the new value to be available in your next line.

What you do is this

```js
useEffect(()=>{
  if(roomId !== null)
     dispatch(createRoom(roomId));
},[roomId]);
```

That way, the callback of useEffect runs everytime your `roomId` changes

Answer (score 1):

```
useEffect(()=>{

 !!roomId && dispatch(createRoom(roomId));

},[roomId]);
```

Comment: wouldn't give desirable result when roomID=0

Comment: @D.B.K please check question, `roomId` is initialized with `empty string` not with `zero` check it `const [roomId, setRoomId] = useState("");`

Comment: yeah ..but for all we know, room ID could be "0" which is still a falsy

Comment: With "0" roomId, !!roomId would be true dear.

Comment: ahh I see. "0"==false returns true, so I assumed. My bad

Comment: Then give a like to my comment and answer :)